# AWS Amplify libraries break Expo app with TypeErrors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo, aws-amplify

I have an expo react native project that uses Amplify for Authentication. When I include any Amplify library I start getting the bellow errors.

```
 ERROR  TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, js engine: hermes
    at RootRouteNodeProvider (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:143613:23)
    at ContextNavigator (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:148703:24)
    at RNCSafeAreaProvider
    at SafeAreaProvider (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:136559:24)
    at RNGestureHandlerRootView
    at GestureHandlerRootView
    at GestureHandler
    at ExpoRoot (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:148688:24)
    at App
    at withDevTools(App) (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:128372:27)
    at RCTView
    at View (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:61481:43)
    at RCTView
    at View (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:61481:43)
    at AppContainer (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:61342:36)
    at main(RootComponent) (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:107126:28)
 ERROR  TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, js engine: hermes
    at RootRouteNodeProvider (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:143613:23)
    at ContextNavigator (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:148703:24)
    at RNCSafeAreaProvider
    at SafeAreaProvider (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:136559:24)
    at RNGestureHandlerRootView
    at GestureHandlerRootView
    at GestureHandler
    at ExpoRoot (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:148688:24)
    at App
    at withDevTools(App) (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:128372:27)
    at RCTView
    at View (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:61481:43)
    at RCTView
    at View (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:61481:43)
    at AppContainer (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:61342:36)
    at main(RootComponent) (http://192.168.0.15:19000/index.tsx.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:107126:28)
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'unstable_settings' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in RootRouteNodeProvider (created by ContextNavigator)
    in ContextNavigator (created by ExpoRoot)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by ExpoRoot)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandler)
    in GestureHandler (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'unstable_settings' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in RootRouteNodeProvider (created by ContextNavigator)
    in ContextNavigator (created by ExpoRoot)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by ExpoRoot)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandler)
    in GestureHandler (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

Here is what I import for example, and it breaks.

```js
import { CognitoAccessToken } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
import { HubCapsule } from "@aws-amplify/core/lib/Hub";
import { CognitoUserSession } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
import { Auth, Hub, Logger } from "aws-amplify";
import { useEffect } from "react";
```

But if I only import

`import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react-native';`

It also breaks the app.

Here are my deps

```json
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@aws-amplify/ui-react-native": "1.2.18",
        "@expo/metro-config": "0.7.1",
        "@expo/vector-icons": "13.0.0",
        "@octokit/core": "4.2.0",
        "@pchmn/expo-material3-theme": "1.0.0",
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
        "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
        "@tanstack/react-query": "4.29.3",
        "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "6.2.0",
        "aws-amplify": "5.1.2",
        "metro-cache": "0.76.5",
        "expo": "48.0.17",
        "expo-asset": "8.9.1",
        "expo-constants": "14.2.1",
        "expo-linking": "4.0.1",
        "expo-modules-autolinking": "1.1.2",
        "expo-router": "1.5.3",
        "expo-secure-store": "12.1.1",
        "expo-splash-screen": "0.18.1",
        "expo-status-bar": "1.4.4",
        "immer": "9.0.21",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.71.8",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.9.0",
        "react-native-paper": "5.5.2",
        "react-native-reanimated": "2.14.4",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
        "react-native-screens": "3.20.0",
        "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
        "react-native-url-polyfill": "1.3.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "9.2.0",
        "react-native-web": "0.18.12",
        "zustand": "4.3.7"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "7.21.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0",
        "@babel/runtime": "7.21.0",
        "@expo/metro-runtime": "2.0.4",
        "@tsconfig/react-native": "2.0.3",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
        "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-loader": "8.0.0-beta.6",
        "babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "0.4.4",
        "dotenv-cli": "^7.1.0",
        "metro": "0.76.5",
        "metro-config": "0.76.5",
        "react-native-svg-transformer": "1.0.0",
        "rome": "12.1.0",
        "typescript": "4.9.5",
        "webpack": "4.23.1",
        "webpack-cli": "3.1.2"
    },
    "private": true
}
```